# Matlab function will not output workable equation

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, argument-passing

I'm trying to have my function file output a workable equation that it calculates, Enth. I have h declared as an anonymous function, but when the program is read the error reads:"Enth is an undefined variable/function". I have a matrix, A, defined from which values are pulled.

```
function [Enth]= Enthalpy(num, H)

syms t; %Declare t 
ntotal=0;      
for i=1:1:num %Request mass of each species
n(i)=input('Enter mass fraction of next species in kg: ');
ntotal=ntotal+n(i); %Running total of mass fractions
hs(i)= (A(i,1)*t)+(A(i,2)/2*t^2)+(A(i,3)/3*t^3)+(A(i,4)/4*t^4)+(A(i,5)/5*t^5)+A(i,6);
end

Enth=@(t)(n(1)*hs(1)+n(2)*hs(2)+n(3)*hs(3)-H);
```

How can I get Enth to be output as a workable equation of 't'? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you calling the function?  Where does `A` come from? (If it's in the base workspace, the function won't be able to see it).

Answer (score 0):

While there might not be much of an advantage in using anonymous function here, some pointers:

1) Don't use `syms`.  `t` is the input into your anonymous function, not a symbolic variable.

2) Define each `hs` in the loop as a single anonymous function based on `t`.

3) Calculate `Enth` as a function of anonymous function as so:

```
function [Enth]= Enthalpy(num, A, H)

ntotal=0;      
for i=1:1:num %Request mass of each species
n(i)=input('Enter mass fraction of next species in kg: ');
ntotal=ntotal+n(i); %Running total of mass fractions
hs{i}= @(t)(A(i,1)*t)+(A(i,2)/2*t^2)+(A(i,3)/3*t^3)+(A(i,4)/4*t^4)+(A(i,5)/5*t^5)+A(i,6);
end

Enth=@(t)(n(1).*hs{1}(t)+n(2)*hs{2}(t)+n(3)*hs{3}(t)-H);
```

I would also suggest you use `./`, `.*`, and `.^` (element-wise division, multiplication, powers, etc) - that way you can pass a vector of `t` rather than a single value.  At the moment, your definition of `Enth` also assumes `num` is 3. If it's less than three, you'll get an error, if it's more than three you're not using some of the input.

In this case, once you have all your `n` values, instead of defining things in the loop you can calculate a single anonymous function at the end.  e.g. rather than the equivalent of `n(1)*A(i,1)*t + n(2)*A(i,2)*t...` you would have something like `@(t) n.*A(1:num,1).*t+n.*A(1:num,2)./2*t.^2...`